# Understanding how do the coverage modules work

Tags: code-coverage

I came across with a new dynamic language. I would like to create a coverage tool for that language. I started reading the source code of Perl 5 and Python coverage modules but it got complicated. It's a dynamic scripting language so I guess that source code of static languages (like Java & C++) won't help me here. Also, as I understand, each language was built in a different way and the same ideas won't work. But, the big concepts could be similar.

My question is as follows: how do I "attack" this task? What is the proper workflow I need to follow? What I need to investigate? Are there any books or blogs I can read about those kind of stuff?

Answer (score 0):

There are two kinds of coverage collection mechanisms:

1) Real-time sampling of the program counter, typically by a clock running at 1-10ms.   Difficulties:  a) mapping an actual PC value back to a source line, b) sampling means  you might not see execution of a rarely used bit of code, so your coverage reporting is inaccurate.  Because of these issues, this approach isn't used very often.

2) Instrumenting the program so that it collects coverage as it runs.   This is hard to do with object code... a) you have to decode the instructions to see where to put probes, and this can be very hard to do right, b) you have patch the source code to include the probes (this can be really awkward; a "probe" might consist of a 5 byte subroutine call but the probe has replace a single-byte instruction). c) you still have to figure out how to map a probe location back to a source code line.   A more effective way is to instrument the source code, which requires pretty sophisticated machinery to read source, make probe patches, and regenerate the instrumented code for execution/compilation.

My technical paper [Branch Coverage for Arbitrary Languages Made Easy](http://www.semdesigns.com/Company/Publications/TestCoverage.pdf) provides explicit detail for how to do this in a general way.   My company has built commercial test coverage tools for a wide variety of languages (C, Python, PHP, COBOL, Java, C++, C#, ProC,....)  using this approach.  This covers most static and dynamic languages.   *Some* dynamic mechanisms are extremely difficult to instrument, e.g., eval()  but that is true of every approach.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Ira's answer, there is a third coverage collection mechanism: the language implementation provides a callback that can inform you about program events.  For example, Python has sys.settrace: you provide it a function, and Python calls your function for every function called or returned, and every line executed.

Comment: True.  Pretty rare; you have to get the language implementers to provide this for you.  I suspect OP's language isn't like that.